# for a given Bitbucket Pull Request , i need to find out Target Merge Branch of this PR

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

For a given Pull Request , i need to find out Merge Target of this PR , whether this PR will merge   one branch  to another branch  or   one branch to main master branch.     is there any git command to do the same?  BitBucket API via python/curl are not preferred option.

system is  git v1.18 on Centos , repo is private BitBucket .

git show-refs , git log did not not help.

Comment: While i haven't used BitBucket, pull requests are not part of `git` itself, so I don't think there's a way to access information about pull requests without using external APIs.

Comment: Not with git. PRs are not a git concept.

Comment: @rajesh this has nothing to do with c , Linux or c++ please don’t spam tags

Comment: ... or linux, for that matter... or _git_ if it's about PRs :-D

Comment: removing git was a joke. Just in case, 1.18 is _very_ old git.

Comment: In git, at least, you could get the upstream branch for a given branch.... it's not like a bullet-proof approach, but at least it is _something_. `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref some-branch@{u}`... and it _might_ be the answer, depending on your workflow.

Comment: Git does not know the target merge branch of a PR, unless BitBucket stores that info in a git object. BitBucket API is the right tool to do the job.

Comment: understood. will go with Rest API way. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such GIT command, as others mentioned, Pull Requests are not part of GIT itself.

You need to go via the Bitbucket API :(